# Need to set cron for random intervals with iMacros

Tags: google-chrome, macros, cron, imacros

I am trying to learn about cron for iMacros but I don't know where to look. Google was no help.

Basically I have  script I wrote, a series of commands, like this:

```
Line 1
Line 2
Line 3
```

etc.

What I want to do, is to run, say, 10 lines every 5-10 minutes (randomly decide a time within 5 and 10 minutes), and between each line to have a time interval, of say, 2 to 5 seconds in between (randomly decide a time within 2 and 5 seconds).

I am new to iMacros and don't know where to begin learning their scripting language. I was however able to write a few really nice scripts that work very well, but I don't know how to write cron for it.

In short, it should look something like this (I substituted code with a description of the cron I want; "Line 1" is just a filler for the code which I want to run cron on):

```
Line 1 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 2 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 3 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 4 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 5 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 6 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 7 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 8 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 9 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 10 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
 [run cron, between 5 and 10 minutes before executing next line]
Line 11 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 12 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 13 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 14 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 15 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 16 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 17 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 18 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 19 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 20 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
 [run cron, between 5 and 10 minutes before executing next line]
Line 21 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 22 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 23 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 24 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 25 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 26 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 27 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 28 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 29 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
Line 30 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
 [run cron, between 5 and 10 minutes before executing next line]
Line 31 [run cron, between 2 and 5 seconds before executing next line]
```

etc.

---

It would be even better if I could have a script, something like the following, but I wouldn't know where to begin:

```
[run sets of 10 lines, consecutively increasing number x, "Line x" x+1, waiting between 2 and 5 seconds before executing each line; then after each set of 10, pause for randomly generated interval of between 5 and 10 minutes before executing next set; repeat]
```

Answer (score 0):

iMacros by itself will not run anything this complicated. However you can combine it with java or any web programming language and accomplish that.

Here's a link to the [iMacros Tutorial](http://wiki.imacros.net/iMacros_for_Firefox) and here's a little [overview of the web scripting capabilities](http://www.iopus.com/imacros/tutorials/java.htm).